# Ruby on Rails - Ruby 2.5.0 and Rails 5.2.3 on Ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, rubygems

I am having trouble installing Ruby 2.5.0 , Rails 5.2.3 on  hyper-v Ubuntu 22.04
This is what I've done so far:

```
sudo apt update

sudo apt install git curl libssl-dev libreadline-dev zlib1g-dev autoconf bison build-essential libyaml-dev libreadline-dev libncurses5-dev libffi-dev libgdbm-dev

curl -fsSL https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv-installer/raw/HEAD/bin/rbenv-installer | bash

echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc

echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.bashrc

source ~/.bashrc

rbenv install 2.5.0

rbenv global 2.5.0

echo "gem: --no-document" > ~/.gemrc

gem install bundler

Error installing bundler:
    The last version of bundler (>= 0) to support your Ruby & RubyGems was 2.3.26. Try installing it with `gem install bundler -v 2.3.26`
    bundler requires Ruby version >= 2.6.0. The current ruby version is 2.5.0.
```

I followed the suggestion and did `gem install bundler -v 2.3.26`, which does install bundler 2.3.26

Then I tried installing rails:

```
gem install rails -v 5.2.3

Fetching: concurrent-ruby-1.2.2.gem (100%)
Successfully installed concurrent-ruby-1.2.2
Fetching: thread_safe-0.3.6.gem (100%)
Successfully installed thread_safe-0.3.6
Fetching: tzinfo-1.2.11.gem (100%)
Successfully installed tzinfo-1.2.11
Fetching: i18n-1.14.1.gem (100%)
Successfully installed i18n-1.14.1
Fetching: activesupport-5.2.3.gem (100%)
Successfully installed activesupport-5.2.3
Fetching: racc-1.7.1.gem (100%)
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
Successfully installed racc-1.7.1
Fetching: nokogiri-1.15.4-x86_64-linux.gem (100%)
**ERROR:  Error installing rails:
    The last version of nokogiri (>= 1.6) to support your Ruby & RubyGems was 1.12.5. Try installing it with `gem install nokogiri -v 1.12.5` and then running the current command again
    nokogiri requires Ruby version < 3.3.dev, >= 2.7. The current ruby version is 2.5.0.**
```

I tried `gem update --system` and it's variations as suggested by some posts, but that gives an error as well:

```
**ERROR:  Error installing rubygems-update:
    There are no versions of rubygems-update (= 3.4.19) compatible with your Ruby & RubyGems
    rubygems-update requires Ruby version >= 2.6.0. The current ruby version is 2.5.0.**
```

I cannot upgrade the project from ruby from 2.5.0 , and cannot install rails....

**EDIT:** RoR first timer, I'm trying to set up a dev environment for a project I've been given, it's already in prod. Trying to replicate it in dev.

Comment: Upgrading your Ruby version is the easiest course -- otherwise you will need to lock down nokogiri in your gemfile to an older version.

Comment: Is there a good reason for installing these old, no-longer-supported, versions of ruby and rails? Do you have an existing project, with a `Gemfile.lock` that specifies all the dependencies?

Comment: @TomLord I've Edited the question explaining why I'm trying to install old version

Answer (score 0):

You  will have to iterate.  Try the bundle install and when it says some gem has to be at an earlier version add it to the Gemfile specifying the version to install and redo the bundle install.

In this instance add `'nokogiri', '1.12'` to your Gemfile and try again.  You may come up with similar instances and the answer is to specify a usable version in the Gemfile.

This is the problem when working with old versions of either Ruby or Rails.  The gems keep getting updated and the current versions may not be compatible with your configuration.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).